# Finding the matrix representation of L with respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

### Problem

Let $V$ be the vector space of all $2 x 2 $ symmetric matrices, with a basis $\beta$ consisting of:

\begin{equation*}
\beta = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 0  
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0  \\
0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

We define the linear transformation $L : V  \rightarrow V $:
$$L(A)=S^TA S$$
for $A \in V$ and \begin{equation*}S = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
0 & 3  
\end{bmatrix} \end{equation*}

**Find the matrix representation $B$ of $L$ with the respect to the basis $\beta$**

### My attempt

I defined A to be:
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
a & b  \\
b & c  
\end{bmatrix}$$

I then compute $L(A)$ :
$$L(A) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & a+6b+9c
\end{bmatrix}$$

After this I am not sure what to do, the textbook answer for $B$ is:
$$B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 6 & 9
\end{bmatrix}$$

### Question

I am completely stuck and I do not know how to proceed to get the same answer as the book. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand why $B$ is a $3\times3$ matrix?

Comment: @amd I do not, after reading Omnomnomnom's answer I understand how I can calculate it though.

Comment: Well, what is $\dim V$?

Comment: @amd Is it $2$?

Comment: Don’t guess. Count basis vectors.

Comment: @amd It is 3! (By counting the basis vectors)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107369/discussion-between-dondeman-and-amd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite your formula for $L(A)$ as follows: if $\beta = \{M_1,M_2,M_3\}$, then 
$$
L(a M_1 + bM_2 + cM_3) = 0M_1 + 0M_2 + (a + 6b + 9c) M_3.
$$
If we rewrite this in terms of the coordinate vectors (of the input and output) relative to $\beta$, we find that the matrix $B$ that represents your linear transformation must satisfy
$$
B \pmatrix{a\\b\\c} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\a + 6b + 9c}.
$$
It is clear, then, that the matrix $B$ that we're looking for is the matrix of coefficients in the right-hand-side expression.

Comment: This is a very smart method, would there be a way of writing $L(A)$ by B-basis without actually rewriting the formula? ( I am just curious, your solution is more than adequate, I am just trying to understand the method a little bit better. Thank you.

Comment: @dondeman The key, whatever your method, is to understand the definition of the matrix of a linear transformation relative to a basis $\beta$. If we are to use the definition, then the most straightforward approach is to write an equation describing $L$ in terms of the elements of the basis $\beta$. Instead of writing out $L(aM_1 + bM_2 + cM_3)$ in its full form, we could also have extracted the columns of $B$ by finding the coordinate vectors of $L(M_1),L(M_2),L(M_3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $L(\beta_1) = \beta_3$, $L(\beta_2) = 6 \beta_3$, $L(\beta_3) = 9\beta_3$.